# Wie nennt man die Bügelflaschen, in denen man Bier aus der Kneipe mitnehmen kann?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Manche kleinen Brauereien und Restaurants bieten Bier zum Mitnehmen an. Das wird dann frisch aus dem Faß in z.B. eine große Bügelflasche gefüllt.

Im Englischen heißen die Dinger [Growler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growler_(jug)), aber wie heißen sie im Deutschen? Einfach nur "große Bügelflasche"? Auch "Growler"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Langenscheidt übersetzt es als

> [Bierkrug / Bierkanne](https://de.langenscheidt.com/englisch-deutsch/growler)

»Bierkanne« ([Bilder](https://www.google.de/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=923&q=bierkanne&btnG=Bildersuche&oq=&gs_l=bierkanne)) ist wohl die bessere Lösung, in Anlehnung an »Milchkanne« [(Bilder)](https://www.google.de/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=923&q=milchkanne&btnG=Bildersuche&oq=&gs_l=milchkanne), die teils ebenfalls mit Bügel ausgestattet ist. Im einen Fall zapfst du unter der Kuh ab, im anderen hinter dem Tresen. Das aber auch nur, solange es noch keine Bierkuh gibt. (Ich höre schon den ersten Trinker seine Frau anbrüllen: »Mach die Kuh leer!«)

Comment: Das Abzapfen von Milch "unter der Kuh" findet gemeinhin nicht mit einer Milchkann statt sondern mit einem Eimer (wenn denn das "Abzapfen" manuell erfolgt und nicht mit der Melkmaschine). Die Milchkanne ist das Gefäß, in das die Milch *hernach* geschüttert wird (oder wurde, denn heute sind Milchkannen nicht mehr verbreitet; vielmehr werden große, in Wagen einhängbare Kühlgefäße verwendet, je nach Betriebsgröße z.B. mit 500-1000 Litern Fassungsvermögen.).

Answer (score 6):

Ich glaube nicht, dass es dafür einen speziellen Namen im Deutschen gibt.

In einem Brauhaus, das ich kenne, werden die Flaschen als

> Bier in der 3l-Mitnahmeflasche

beworben.

Answer (score 5):

Traditionell bzw. in der Fachsprache der Getränkeindustrie gibt es den Ausdruck [Biersiphon](http://brauen.de/brauzubehoer/bierkruege-und-biersiphon/biersiphon/) für derartige Flaschen. Im normalen Alltagsdeutsch ist dieser Begriff jedoch kaum verbreitet, nur wenige deutsche Muttersprachler werden wissen, was damit gemeint ist. "Große Bügelflasche" wird hingegen allgemein verstanden.